# Sum involving ${\frak{S}}_n$-character values and Kostka numbers

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

Let $\lambda$, $\mu$, and $\rho$ be partitions of $n$ and let
$\chi^\lambda_\rho$ and $K_{\lambda \mu}$ denote the associated ${\frak{S}}_n$-character value and Kostka number respectively.

**Question:** Is there a good combinatorial and/or representation-theoretic interpretation of the quantity

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \, \chi^\lambda_\rho K_{\lambda \mu}
\end{equation}

What happens if I replace $K_{\lambda \mu}$ by the Kostka-Foulkes polynomial $K_{\lambda \mu}(t)$ ?

thanks, ines.

Comment: I may have the placement of indices wrong, but isn't it the character of the Young module? (as in formula 4.31 in Fulton-Harris).

Comment: Yes --- it seems Fulton-Harris reverses the role of $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Thank you !

Comment: @Abdelmalkek Abdesselam Am I right that this quantity, perhaps up to some overall global $t$-monomial, defines the so called *Green* function/polynomial $X^\mu_\rho(t)$ when the Kostka number is replaced by the Kostka-Foulkes polynomial $K_{\lambda \mu}(t) ?$

Comment: Sorry, I am  not familiar with the $t$ version.